# Binomial Theorem proof using three terms

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If $$(6-12x+12x^2)^n =\sum\limits_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}x^r$$ then prove that
$$a_{r} = (-1)^r3^n2^r\left[{2n \choose r} + {n \choose 1}{(2n - 2) \choose r} + {n \choose 2}{(2n-4) \choose r} + \cdots \right]$$

I tried to expand the binomial by grouping the first two terms as one term and the third term as second term.
$$
\begin{split}
(6-12x+12x^2)^n & = \big((6-12x)+12x^2\big)^n \\
&= (6-12x)^n + {n \choose 1}(6-12x)^{(n-1)}12x^2 \\
&\quad+ {n \choose 2}(6-12x)^{(n-2)}\big(12x^2\big)^2 + {n \choose 3}(6-12x)^{(n-3)}\big(12x^2\big)^3 + \ldots + {n \choose n}\big(12x^2\big)^n.
\end{split}
$$
Then I extracted the power of $x^r$:
$${n \choose r}6^{n-r}(-12)^r + {n \choose 1}{n-1 \choose r-2}6^{n-r+1}(-12)^{r-2} +  {n \choose 2}{n-2 \choose r-4}6^{n-r+2}(-12)^{r-4} + \ldots 
$$
After this step I was clueless how to proceed to achieve the right hand side of equality and conclude the proof.

Comment: Sourav, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed by moderators because it is a very bad and low-quality question.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes it is $3^n$

Comment: @Angelo Thanks for the suggestions and sorry for not being detailed. I have updated the question. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332121

Comment: Sourav, your post is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332121), so you should delete your question.

Comment: @Angelo It is not a duplicate of that question, it is a special case, and this question may indeed be possible.

Comment: @ancientmathematician, a special case is a particular type of a duplicate.

Comment: Personally I would get rid of the $6$ and the $(-1)$ and look at the expansion of $(1+2x+2x^2)^n$, and I'd expand it as $[x^2+ (1+x)^2]^n$, followed by expansion of $(1+x)^{2n-2k}$; the correct binomial coefficients turn up but I haven't checked the details.

Comment: @Angelo Not if the special case has an interesting special answer.

Comment: @Angelo I mentionned that post as "related" but it is not a duplicate because that general case only gives a formula which "In general, cannot be simplified further", so it does not (at least not obviously) provide a solution for the present special case.

Comment: Well, you can sort of see and accept how combining of terms should lead to an answer like that be actually  trying to keep the terms under control and not have them spilling off the paper onto the floor and down the airducts might be a headache.  I'd suggest this is a perfect case to try a proof by induction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the the coefficient of $\,x^r\,$ in $\,(1+x+x^2)^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714246/find-the-the-coefficient-of-xr-in-1xx2n)

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein It doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Sourav Could you please edit your post to be more explicit on you attempt (i.e. type all the formulas of it instead of describing them), and ask for a reopening of your post?

Comment: @AnneBauval That was an automatic comment from a close vote.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I know. That was a doubt about the opinion (via that close vote) that this post is a duplicate of the linked one.

Comment: @AnneBauval Would you like to reopen it? I think you can.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein I do not dare to vote for reopening, because it was not closed "as a duplicate" but for lack of "context", and Sourav still didn't edit his post to be more explicit on his attempt, as I asked him yesterday.

Comment: @AnneBauval As per your suggestion, I have provided detailed steps and requested for reopening the post.

Answer (score 3):

Even if we were not given the value of the $a_r$s, we could discover it (and thereby prove it), by expanding $(6-12x+12x^2)^n$ with two consecutive uses of the binomial theorem, and a change of the order of summation:
$$\begin{align}(6-12x+12x^2)^n&=3^n\left(1+(2x-1)^2\right)^n\\&=3^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(2x-1)^{2(n-k)}\\&=3^n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\sum_{r=0}^{2(n-k)}\binom{2(n-k)}r  (2x)^r(-1)^{2(n-k)-r}\\&=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_rx^r
\end{align}$$
with
$$a_r=3^n(-2)^r\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{2(n-k)}r.$$

Note that all along these calculations, the lower and upper bounds in the sums were actually superfluous. We could as well write $\sum_{k\in\Bbb N}$ and $\sum_{r\in\Bbb N}$, with the convention that $\binom pq=0$ if $q>p$.

More generally, you can use this method to prove that
$$((ax+b)^2+c)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}a_rx^r$$
with
$$a_r=b^{2n}\left(\frac ab\right)^r\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk\binom{2(n-k)}r\left(\frac c{b^2}\right)^k.$$

Answer (score 0):

Induction:

$(6-12x+12x^2)^n =\sum\limits_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}x^r$

So $(6-12x + 12x^2)^{n+1} = (6 - 12x +12x^2)\sum\limits_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}x^r=$

$6\sum\limits_{r=0}^{2n}a_{r}x^r + 12\sum\limits_{r=1}^{2n+1}a_{r-1}x^r+ 12\sum\limits_{r=2}^{2n+2}a_{r-2}x^r$

So if $(6-12x + 12x^2)^{n+1}=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{2(n+1)}b_rx^r$

we have $b_0=6a_0; b_1 = 6a_1 + 12a_0$ and for $2\le r \le 2n$ we have $b_r=6a_r +12a_{r-1} + 12_{r-2}$ and $b_{2n+1} = 12a_{2n} + 12a+{2n-1}$ and $b_{2n+2}= 12a_{2n}$.

Plug in $a_{r} = (-1)^r.3^n.2^r.({2n \choose r} + {n \choose 1}.{(2n - 2) \choose r} + {n \choose 2}. {(2n-4) \choose r} + ... )$

And if we we are correct, this should yield:

$b_r = (-1)^r.3^{n+1}.2^r.({2n+2 \choose r} + {n+1 \choose 1}.{2n \choose r} + {n+1 \choose 2}. {(2n-2) \choose r} + ... )$